# Ubuntu 12.04 Mobile Broadband Settings with Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, 3g, mobile-broadband

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to my beaglebone and now want to make appropriate changes to be able to use my Huawei e173 modem. I can successfully use Huawei e173 on my desktop ubuntu 12.04. But I cannot use the same method on my beaglebone. Because I can only use terminal screen. Therefore I thought if I know the files that my desktop PC modifies for mobile broadband settings, than I can copy them to the beaglebone and start using Huawei modem. However I could not find all the files that are related to mobile broadband settings.

Seems like all the files under /etc/ppp are related
/usr/sbin/chat is related
/etc/chatscripts/pap is related.

What more do I need? For example I could not figure out where it saves my 3g modem's password. Where is it located?

Regards

Answer (score -2):

You can use find to find all files changes since a timestamp file.

in bash:

```
touch time-stamp-file
set up modem
find / -newer time-stamp-file
```

This method finds a few false positives, but should find all files you are looking for.